# Get a particular list of String using Regex in java

Tags: java, regex, parsing

My string will look like this,

```
lopsakf pkpsdkf pskadp fkpsdkfp sdaf
oksflksflslkf sdlf kasldfk lasdkf lsadfk 
lopsakf pkpsdkf pskadp fkpsdkfp sdaf
oksflksflslkf sdlf kasldfk lasdkf lsadfk lopsakf pkpsdkf pskadp fkpsdkfp sdaf
oksflksflslkf sdlf kasldfk lasdkf lsadfk 

[[test: lls]]
[[test: askd]]
[[test: mmdm]]
[[test: owow]]
[[test: www]]
[[test: wowow]]
```

I would like to get the values lls, askd, mmdm, etc.. and store it in a List. Please note that there are huge volume of such texts. I need an efficient way to parse each set and store it in a List,without using any external libraries.

Comment: *"I need an.."* ..demonstration of (any) effort, as well as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the regular expression:

```
(?<=\[\[test: )[^]]+
```

In ahother hand, you need to use a constant of [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for avoid recompiled the expression every time, something like that:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[\\[test: )[^]]+");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "lopsakf pkpsdkf pskadp fkpsdkfp sdaf\noksflksflslkf sdlf kasldfk lasdkf lsadfk \nlopsakf pkpsdkf pskadp fkpsdkfp sdaf\noksflksflslkf sdlf kasldfk lasdkf lsadfk lopsakf pkpsdkf pskadp fkpsdkfp sdaf\noksflksflslkf sdlf kasldfk lasdkf lsadfk \n\n[[test: lls]]\n[[test: askd]]\n[[test: mmdm]]\n[[test: owow]]\n[[test: www]]\n[[test: wowow]]";

    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
lls
askd
mmdm
owow
www
wowow
```

Use `matcher.find()` and `matcher.group()` for get the required strings.

In another way, use a instance of [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) with an initial capacity already defined, according to the number of strings that may exist, so that the list should not be required copy the elements to a new internal array.

Answer (score 1):

```
\[\[test:\s([\w]+)\]\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/7-uvca6GHYW0_4gg)

it essentially captures `[[test: *any number and character here* ]]` in a capture group which generally returns as an array.

[Info About Capture Groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html)

**NOTE:** you maybe need to escape characters (I.E. \\[)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below using a `Matcher` to extract each string and add it to a list should work (regex is untested):

```
String input = "My input string....";

List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
String pattern = "\\[\\[test: (\\w+)\\]\\]";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(input);
while (matcher.find())
{
    String matchedString = matcher.group(1);
    myStrings.add(matchedString);
}
```

You could also add to a `Set` instead of a `List` if you want to avoid duplicate strings.

In terms of efficiency, you could write a more efficient solution parsing the string yourself character by character and avoiding the regex overhead, but the gains are likely not worth the effort of such an undertaking.